# silverlight for VS-2008(SP-1)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

i have installed silverlight 4,but in VS-2008(SP-1) it doesnt show option for creating silverlight project.does VS-2008(SP-1) supports silverlight 4? or which version of silverlight 
should i use?
thanks.

Comment: @user594979, I notice that you have 11 questions but have not given any upvotes, it is normal to upvote answers that help you

Comment: @Shiraz: 15 rep is required to upvote answers, at this time user594979 does not have enought rep.

Comment: @Anthony, my bad, +1 now he does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Microsoft did not add support for Silverlight 4 in VS2008, that was moved to VS2010 instead.

You can use Silverlight 2 only. I've seen some tries to include SL3 but there were some problems.

Comment: Silverlight 3 is supported in Visual Studio 2008 SP1. Silverlight 4 is unsupported.